# Adding ProGuard tasks to gradle kotlin

Tags: kotlin, proguard, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to add proguard to project with gradle build system based on kotlin DSL, but I don't understand how to implement everything correctly.

After a huge number of attempts, I came to this version of the task:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.guardsquare:proguard-gradle:7.2.2")
    }
}

// Make jar executable
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = application.mainClass
}

tasks.register<proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask>("proguard") {
    val jarName = "$buildDir/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}"
    injars("$jarName.jar")
    outjars("$jarName-proguard.jar")
}
```

But when running `./gradlew build proguard`, I get the following error:

```
> Task :proguard FAILED
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':proguard' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/i/tms/build/libs/tms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'. Reason: Task ':proguard' uses this output of task ':jar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

How to add proguard to a gradle kotlin project correctly?
Is there a way to make the proguard task depend on the build task so that I can write `./gradlew proguard` instead `./gradlew build proguard`?